# Determining the moment of force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors

A force $F = 3i + 2j$ passes through through a point $P$ with respect to an origin $O$. How do I determine the moment of the force at the origin.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework problem?  Do you not know the equation for the moment of force, or are you having a problem with applying it?  What work have you done on the problem so far before getting stuck?

Comment: I am having problems applying it. Please help. I know that `Moment of force = Force applied × Perpendicular distance from the fixed axis`

Comment: @Lance Moment is the vector product of the displacement from the "pivot" and the force. If you have the coordinates of P, this is a straightforward vector product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torque, or moment of force, is simply $\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$, where $\vec{r}$ is the vector OP, and $\vec{F}$ is your force. Of course changing the origin of your SRS will change the torque.

[image: CRS]

By the way, this is not the place for homework related questions!